# Writing text to a txt file and it's adding an extra line

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
with open("recordsAudit.txt", "w") as databasefile:
    for auditer, auditdate in zip(auditers, audit_Date):
        databasefile.write("%s, %s\n" % (auditer, auditdate))
```

In the auditers and audit_Date list we can find:

```
auditers = [Frank Price, Robert Real]
audit_Date = [6/30/2022, 7/5/2022]
```

When I open "recordsAudit.txt" I find this:

```
William Silva, 6/30/2022

Robert Real, 7/5/2022
```

But I want this:

```
William Silva, 6/30/2022
Robert Real, 7/5/2022
```

If I take away the "\n" at the end, it turns to this:

```
William Silva, 6/30/2022Robert Real, 7/5/2022
```

Comment: https://newbedev.com/python-file-write-creating-extra-carriage-return

Comment: Try `databasefile.write("%s, %s\n" % (auditer.strip(), auditdate.strip()))`

Comment: Your lists are syntactically malformed. Assuming the elements are strings you will **not** get any extra lines in the output file unless one of the aforementioned strings also contains a newline character